How to use Cloudformation to set Conditional EFS Replication?
Cloudformation allows you to make conditional values for things. For example I am able to conditionally turn on EFS Backup Policy (see BackupPolicy below). But I'm unable to do conditional replication, because if you call the "ReplicationConfiguration" attribute it forces you to set it to a valid replication value. Basically, I can't specify  ReplicationConfiguration to 'Not Replicate' which means I can't use cloudformation 'If' function. If it did work, I'd expect it to look something like the code below.
    "DemoEfs": {
      "Type": "AWS::EFS::FileSystem",
      "Properties": {
        "Encrypted": false,
        "PerformanceMode": "generalPurpose",
        "BackupPolicy": { "Fn::If": [
          "ProdOnly",
          { "Status" : "ENABLED" },
          { "Status" : "DISABLED" }
        ] },
        "ReplicationConfiguration": { "Fn::If": [
          "ProdOnly",
          { "Destinations" : [ { "Region" : "us-west-2" } ] },
          { "Destinations" : [] }
        ] }
      }
    },

Can someone tell me if there is a way to do conditional EFS replication that works?
